# abstract class field set in @Scheduled cannnot be accessed by implementation instance

Tags: java, spring-boot, cglib

I wrote a abstract class to manage timed activities in a game. The game uses `SpringBoot` and cglib proxy.

```
public abstract class TimedImpl extends PlanImpl {
    protected TimedPlan schedule;

    public TimedPlan getSchedule() {
        return schedule;
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = CronConst.PER_MINUTE_1)
    public final void onSchedule() {
        Plan plan = getOngoingPlans()
                .stream()
                .min(Comparator.comparingInt(Plan::getId))
                .orElse(null);
        if (schedule != null && (plan == null || plan.getId() != schedule.getId())) {
            // end
            onEnd();
            schedule = null;
        }
        if (plan != null) {
            if (schedule == null) {
                schedule = new TimedPlan(plan);
            }

            long time = TimeUtil.currentTimeMills();
            int progress = 0;
            long[] period = plan.getPeriod();
            while (progress < period.length && time >= period[progress]) progress ++;
            if (schedule.getState() == progress) {
                return;
            }

            schedule.setState(progress);
            switch (schedule.getState()) {
                case 1:
                    onPrepare();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    onBegin();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onPrepare() {

    }

    protected void onBegin() {

    }

    protected void onEnd() {

    }
}
```

I defined a `KillBossServiceImpl` to extends `TimedImpl`. This activity starts from 8:00 AM and end at 10:00 PM.

At the start of the activity, the `schedule` was assigned in `onSchedule()` and not null.
But afterwards, before the activity end,  each time I call the `getSchedule()` from member methods or `onEnd()` in `KillBossServiceImpl`, it returns null.

However, each minute upon the execution of `onSchedule()`, the `schedule` is the previous assigned value and not null.

After some google, it seems there's two diffrent instances of `KillBossServiceImpl`, and one is proxy instance generated by cglib. How to call the `getSchedule` on right instance?

---

Update:

It turns out that `onSchdule` is using the proxy instance by printing:

```
this.getClass().getName(); // com.xx.xx.KillBossServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1
```

Comment: Remove `final` as that prevents the proxy to be applied and instead of passing it to the real object it is executed on the proxy which doesn't have anything set.

Comment: Thanks! I can get the `schedule` on real object now!